# Determining variations of Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an alert dependent on an array containing around 38 of the 50 United States, It works fine (thanks to help from you wonderful people) but now I'm concerned users may input variations of the format I am using currently which is two uppercase letters (i.e. WA, OR, GA etc). What if they are to input lowercase (i.e. wa, or, ga) or maybe a combination of uppercase and lowercase (i.e. Wa, Or, Ga) or with symbols (i.e. WA - Washington, OR - Oregon, GA - Georgia). Wondering if there is a more accurate way of doing this that will catch all variations.

The alert I'm referring to is the last one, at the bottom pointing toward #address_province.

Please note I am very new at using both Javascript and jQuery so as much detail as you can offer is appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
<script>
// Hides shipping info fieldset if ship to billing is checked
$(function () {
    $("#ship_to_billing").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) $("#shipping_info").hide();
        else $("#shipping_info").show();
    });
});

// Validates address fields are filled out unless ship to billing is checked...   
function validateShipping() {
    if (!$("#ship_to_billing").is(":checked")) {
        var inputs = $("#shipping_info input");
        var ready = true;
        inputs.each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                ready = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (!ready) {
            alert("Please tell us where to send this. Either choose ship to Billing Address or fill out both the Recipient Name as well as Shipping Address fields. Thanks!");
            return false;
        }
    }
        // Makes sure age verification is checked 
        if (!$('#age_verification').is(':checked')) {
            alert("Please verify you are 21 years of age or older.");
            return false;       
        }   
      // Confirms province is allowed for wine shipping 
          var states = ["AK", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MI", "MN", "MO", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OR", "SC", "TN", "TX", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"];
              if ($.inArray($("#address_province").val(), states) <0) {
                 alert("Shipping gifts containing alcohol to this state is prohibited by law. Please choose another item.");
                 return false;       
        }
 return true;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Take the first two characters of the input value, convert to uppercase, then compare? Alternatively use a `<select>` that only includes states that are actually valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case concerns can be handled using the [`String.toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) function. You'd simply take the value they've entered, convert it to upper case, and then compare it against the values in your array. So, regardless of whether they enter WA, Wa, wa, or wA, you'll be using WA for the comparison.

The user entering the value in some other format, such as `WA - Washington` can be handled in a few ways. One solution would be to simply take the first two characters (so you'd get `WA`), but that doesn't work if they enter the state name on its own; it would work for Washington, but not for Georgia.

I'd be inclined to enforce a limit of 2 characters on the input box using the `maxlength` attribute (`maxlength="2"`). That should be supported by all browsers and makes it clear that you're expecting a state code rather than a state name.

One final option is, if that validation is always applicable, to use a `<select>` element that only includes valid states. That would remove the need for client-side validation altogether (though you'd still need to do server-side validation).

Comment: Select box is the best option. If you have multiple countries, then you may have to switch between select and text boxes depending on the country.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I am unable to utilize a dropdown/select element in this particular area so ended up enforcing maxlength and utilizing toUpperCase as follows:         if ($.inArray($("#address_province").val().toUpperCase(), states) <0) {                                                                    Thank you for your very in depth and helpful response! Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/uQEJIkU/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var state = "Wisconsin";
  var result = state.slice(0,2).toUpperCase()

  alert(result)

});
```

All merit goes to @Anthony_Grist as he had the first answer in the comment.

Comment: bitoiu-Thank you, appreciate your response!